# Trying to get the cross outside but next to the div

Tags: bootstrap-4

Right now the problem is that the X anchor is inside the div, i want it to be outside the div and next to the div. The image is how it looks now. This is what i have tried, any suggestions or help would be nice.

```
    <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters mb-3">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="risk-container card d-flex flex-row justify-content-between shadow-sm px-3 py-2 mr-2">
            <div class="risk risk-{{ risk.level }}" data-id="{{risk.id}}" data-level="{{ risk.level }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#risk-edit">
                <p class="risk-description"><i class="fas fa-{{ ['bug', 'exclamation-triangle', 'fire'][risk.level] }}"></i> <span class="risk-description-value">{{ risk.description }}</span></p>
                <p class="risk-measure">{{ risk.measure ?: 'Ingen åtgärd registrerad' }}</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="risk-remove text-danger p-2"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[In the picture you can se how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9OMr.png)

Comment: I am not sure which div you are talking about ? can you give an illustration of what you want the result to look like ?

Comment: Outside the risk-container!

Comment: ok, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your X anchor in a different `<div class="col">`. 
If that does not solve the issue, could you add a reproductible exemple to your post ?